# Como paginar 2 listas con laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, laravel

como puedo paginar 2 listas con su paginación cada una que al momento de paginar no cambie los datos en las 2 listas si solo cambie donde estoy paginando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando creas tu query con Eloquent simplemente agregas una palabra distinta que será el parámetro paginador para cada lista, esto se conoce como `$pageName`:

```
$queryLista1->paginate(10, ['*'], 'pagina');

$queryLista2->paginate(5, ['*'], 'paginalista2');
```

Si deseas más info sobre el método, mira en Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php

```
/**
 * Paginate the given query.
 *
 * @param  int  $perPage
 * @param  array  $columns
 * @param  string  $pageName
 * @param  int|null  $page
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
{
    $query = $this->toBase();

    $total = $query->getCountForPagination();

    $this->forPage(
        $page = $page ?: Paginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName),
        $perPage = $perPage ?: $this->model->getPerPage()
    );

    return new LengthAwarePaginator($this->get($columns), $total, $perPage, $page, [
        'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
        'pageName' => $pageName,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Bien me sirvo gracias, ahora sabes algún modo para que la pagina no se actualice al momento de cambiar de paginación, sino que solo cambien los datos de la tabla??